# Groupby sum not producing sum output in Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataset, df, where I would like to groupby a specific column and sum.

```
Type     

A
A
A
B
B
C
```

Desired

```
Type        Count
 
 A           3
 B           2
 C           1
```

Doing:

```
df.groupby(['Type']).sum()
```

However this is the output I am getting when I use the above:

```
A
B
C
```

Any suggestion is appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Check second answer.

Comment: Use `.count()` instead of `.sum()`

Comment: ok I used .size() and this worked. Thank you